# write to logfile if rules are not fulfilled

Tags: python, file-io

I am currently writing a code to scan for files in input folder and copy images, that fulfill the requirements ('rules' list) to another directory. If the file does not accomplish any given requirement, this should be reported to logfile.txt stating something like:

```
Error number 1, file -> data\0055\0100.jpg
```

but with my current code i get repeated outputs to logfile, without relation to rule that is not fulfilled. So, for each file in logfile i have:

```
Error number 1, file -> data\0055\0100.jpg
Error number 2, file -> data\0055\0100.jpg
Error number 3, file -> data\0055\0100.jpg
```

So, how would I write every single entry to logfile with distinct 'rule' number without repetition? Also, how would i check, if copied file in output_dir already exists?

There is my current code:

```
import os
from glob import glob
from PIL import Image
import shutil
from tqdm import tqdm

input_dir = 'data'
output_dir = 'out'

try:
    if os._exists(output_dir) == False:
        os.mkdir(output_dir)
except FileExistsError:
    print('Directory "out" already exists! Proceeding with script')

logfile = open('logfile.txt','w+')

ext = ('jpg', 'jpeg', 'JPG', '.PEG')

dirs = sorted(glob(os.path.join(input_dir, '**/*.jpg'),
                               recursive=True))

def checker(input_dir, output_dir, logfile):
    for i, file in tqdm(enumerate(input_dir), desc='Processing copied files!',
                              total=len(input_dir)):
        rules = [file.endswith(ext),
                 os.path.getsize(file) >= 10000,
                 Image.open(file),

                     ]

        if all(rules):
            # shutil.copy(file, output_dir)
                new_filename = str(i).zfill(6) + '.jpg'
                shutil.copy(file, os.path.join(output_dir, new_filename))
        else:
            for i, rule in enumerate(rules):
                logfile.write(f'\nError number {i+1}, file -> {file}\n')

checker(dirs, output_dir, logfile)
```

Thank you kindly for attention if you are reading this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Image.open(file) call in your code does not return True/False, it returns a file object.  As such, you will not be testing (True/False, True/False, True/False), so the all() test will always return a "fail".

You need to rework the last test in your rules, I think.

Comment: I removed the last rule 'Image.open(file)' but still get repeated entries in logfile, i think problem lies in 'for' loop, but still can't find alternative to it

Comment: Actually, I've found the way out: I made another list before writing to log file which records index of not fulfilled rule everytime and then outputs to the logfile. I'll upvote you for help!

Comment: don't think it's an issue with your loop, as you are actually looping through things, so the loop is, at the very least, providing something to work on.   A different issue, though... in your first rules test you're testing "endswith(<a tuple>)" which means your file will never end with that.  I believe that endswith() will only accept a string, so you need to loop through each member of the members in the tuple, or make a compound test like (file.endswith(ext[0]) or file.endswith(ext[1])...)

Comment: Thank you for noticing! I reworked the first rule as well! My code look like absolute Frankenstein though :D

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution: I made another list before writing to log file which records index of not fulfilled rule everytime and then outputs to the logfile. 
It looks like this:

```
        else:
            errors = [num for (num, state) in enumerate(rules) if not state]
            for num in errors:
                logfile.write(f'{file};{num+1}\n')
```

But one question I still have is how to check if PIL extension opens file without an error?

Answer (score 0):

you were on the right track by opening the file.  Just do the Image.open() with "try:/catch:".  From the [PIL Doc pages](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html):

```
PIL.Image.open(fp, mode='r')
...
Raises: 
IOError – If the file cannot be found, or the image cannot be opened and identified.
...
```

Comment: But to make that work I should write it outside the 'rules' list, right? Also, if i want to convert each image inside the loop to numpy array to check for dimensionality, what is the most effective way to do so in means of performance?

Comment: you could write a function to do an open with a try/catch and return true on success, false on failure... the function would only need to open, verify it opened, then close.  That way you could use function(file) in your rules.  To convert the image you'd need to re-open it inside the loop and deal with it there.  Not sure about performance, but open/close doesn't take too long, though I'm not sure it's terribly efficient.